# cant read last sms in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I want to write a simple app , that show a toast when phone is ringing . the text of the that toast is the Incoming call number's last sms . my toast is working well when phone is ringing but when i want to set toast text to last sms of that number , its don't show any toast  ?!
there is my code :

```
public class callReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private Toast toast;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        toast = new Toast(context);
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            String incomingNumber = intent
                    .getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

            toast.setText(getsmsContent(incomingNumber, context));
            toast.setDuration(600000);
            toast.show();

        } else {
            toast.cancel();
        }    
    }

    public String getsmsContent(String number, Context con) {

        int i = 0;
        String num = null;
        boolean Break = false;
        String smsContent = null;
        Cursor cursor = con.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()
                .query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            num = cursor.getString(2);
            if (num.equals(number)) {
                smsContent = cursor.getString(5);
                Break = true;
            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext() && Break);
        return smsContent;
    }    
}
```

manifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.calltoast2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.calltoast2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="callReciver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Where and how are you registering `callReciver`? Also, you probably want `!Break` in the `while`.

Comment: @MikeM. i used manifest file to describe the broadcastReceiver . its wrong ? its work if i set toast text another thing .... I think my reading sms code has an problem .

Comment: Yeah, that's where you'd want it, but the manifest you've posted doesn't have a `<receiver>` entry for the class `callReciver`. Did you change the `while` as I noted in my previous comment?

Comment: your while loop exit condition is wrong. you want `!Break`

Comment: @MikeM. I put the manifest file wrong ! I edited it . and fixed the while condition . but it's don't work again !

Comment: You want `"content://sms/inbox"` for the URI, and you shouldn't be using constants for the column indices. Let me run a test, and I'll post an answer.

Comment: @MikeM. please test the toast too . thank you so much ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you want to restrict your query to the Inbox, and you shouldn't be using constants for the Cursor indices. Also, we can eliminate the looping altogether if we query on the number.

```
public String getSmsContent(String number, Context context)
{
    String smsContent = "No entry for " + number;

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
        .query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), new String[]{"body"}, "address=?", new String[]{number}, null);

    if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        smsContent = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
    }

    return smsContent;
}
```

---

After further testing, it appears that the number stored in the SMS Provider might not exactly match that received from the incoming call. In this case, I believe we will have to resort to looping in order to check possible matches. Here we use the `PhoneNumberUtils.compare()` method, which will return true if the numbers are "identical enough for caller ID purposes."

```
public String getSmsContent(String number, Context context)
{
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
        .query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), new String[]{"address", "body"}, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            if(PhoneNumberUtils.compare(number, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"))))
            {
                return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
            }
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return "No entry for " + number;
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you've any problems. I can't do a full test right now. I only have one phone, and I can't reach anybody to call me. The only problem I foresee is if the numbers don't match exactly, but I'd think they'd be consistent across the API.

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear it. By the way, I like this idea! Pretty handy.